# Issues with wrapping text around a circle shaped div

Tags: html, css

I know similar questions have been asked previously, but I've been following the guidance of the answers to them and still seem to be getting nowhere.

I'm trying to design a blog. I want a circular image in the bottom right with the article text wrapping around it, but the div with text and the image div don't seem to want to play along. My code is probably quite poor and the solution quite obvious, but please **don't** go easy I need to learn! Any help much appreciated.

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: transparent !important;

}

nav {
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

}

.navtitle {
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.article {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

    background-image: url(http://api.thumbr.it/whitenoise-361x370.png?background=ffffffff&noise=fffcd9&density=66&opacity=44);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60rem;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


.circle {
    width: 28rem;
    height: 28rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: circle();
    margin: 30px;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464802686167-b939a6910659?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1333&q=80);
    background-size: cover;

}

.title {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.articlecontent {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

#mainsection {
    margin-top: 28rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="palebluestyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"><span class="navtitle">Pale Blue Dot.</span></span>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Find Articles" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
  </nav>
</div>

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container" id="mainsection">

<div class="jumbotron mainart">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="title"><h1>Article Title</h1></div>
        <div class="articlecontent">
        <p>Qui tempor excepteur ex anim proident. Pariatur veniam non dolore ut eu excepteur veniam. 
            Elit sunt non culpa duis cupidatat laboris cupidatat reprehenderit sint incididunt aliquip occaecat. 
            Dolore consectetur occaecat deserunt sit ullamco ipsum qui ipsum eiusmod eu culpa occaecatdo. 
            Qui enim non sint consequat aliqua anim est laboris anim Lorem incididunt ad in velit. 
            Esse laboris amet laborum enim magna duis Lorem proident commodo ex.
            Cillum quis irure magna quis dolore. Deserunt tempor aliqua ut laboris cillum dolor cupidatat anim laboris qui. Eu ut sit ut  cupidatat. Lorem occaecat aliquip sit et. Veniam do deserunt sint sunt ad et minim nulla in. Et cupidatat culpa nostrud laboris officia fugiat laboris anim excepteur.
        </p></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
</div>


</div>
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: transparent !important;

}

nav {
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

}

.navtitle {
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.article {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

    background-image: url(http://api.thumbr.it/whitenoise-361x370.png?background=ffffffff&noise=fffcd9&density=66&opacity=44);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60rem;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


.circle {
    width: 28rem;
    height: 28rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: circle();
    margin: 30px;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464802686167-b939a6910659?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1333&q=80);
    background-size: cover;

}

.title {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.articlecontent {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

#mainsection {
    margin-top: 28rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="palebluestyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"><span class="navtitle">Pale Blue Dot.</span></span>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Find Articles" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
  </nav>
</div>

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container" id="mainsection">

<div class="jumbotron mainart">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="title"><h1>Article Title</h1></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="articlecontent">
        <p>Qui tempor excepteur ex anim proident. Pariatur veniam non dolore ut eu excepteur veniam. 
            Elit sunt non culpa duis cupidatat laboris cupidatat reprehenderit sint incididunt aliquip occaecat. 
            Dolore consectetur occaecat deserunt sit ullamco ipsum qui ipsum eiusmod eu culpa occaecatdo. 
            Qui enim non sint consequat aliqua anim est laboris anim Lorem incididunt ad in velit. 
            Esse laboris amet laborum enim magna duis Lorem proident commodo ex.
            Cillum quis irure magna quis dolore. Deserunt tempor aliqua ut laboris cillum dolor cupidatat anim laboris qui. Eu ut sit ut  cupidatat. Lorem occaecat aliquip sit et. Veniam do deserunt sint sunt ad et minim nulla in. Et cupidatat culpa nostrud laboris officia fugiat laboris anim excepteur.
        </p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</div>
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: transparent !important;

}

nav {
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

}

.navtitle {
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.article {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

    background-image: url(http://api.thumbr.it/whitenoise-361x370.png?background=ffffffff&noise=fffcd9&density=66&opacity=44);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    box-shadow: 11px 10px 53px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60rem;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


.circle {
    width: 28rem;
    height: 28rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: right;
    shape-outside: circle();
    margin: 30px;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464802686167-b939a6910659?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1333&q=80);
    background-size: cover;

}

.title {
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: 'Prata', serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.articlecontent {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10px;

}

#mainsection {
    margin-top: 28rem;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="palebluestyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1"><span class="navtitle">Pale Blue Dot.</span></span>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Find Articles" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
  </nav>
</div>

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container" id="mainsection">

<div class="jumbotron mainart">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="title"><h1>Article Title</h1></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="articlecontent">
        <p>Qui tempor excepteur ex anim proident. Pariatur veniam non dolore ut eu excepteur veniam. 
            Elit sunt non culpa duis cupidatat laboris cupidatat reprehenderit sint incididunt aliquip occaecat. 
            Dolore consectetur occaecat deserunt sit ullamco ipsum qui ipsum eiusmod eu culpa occaecatdo. 
            Qui enim non sint consequat aliqua anim est laboris anim Lorem incididunt ad in velit. 
            Esse laboris amet laborum enim magna duis Lorem proident commodo ex.
            Cillum quis irure magna quis dolore. Deserunt tempor aliqua ut laboris cillum dolor cupidatat anim laboris qui. Eu ut sit ut  cupidatat. Lorem occaecat aliquip sit et. Veniam do deserunt sint sunt ad et minim nulla in. Et cupidatat culpa nostrud laboris officia fugiat laboris anim excepteur.
        </p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</div>
        
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```